# How to print xml string from xmlDoc

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am doing is reading xml document from server and i have to make modification to that xml document locally and store the xml document response on server but i am not able to print the changed xml response please help me!!!!

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}


function stringsxmlparsing()
{
console.log("\n\nThis is books.xml demo\n\n");

xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");

//Changing attribute value
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('string');
x[0].setAttribute("name","food");

//Accessing attribute value
txt=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("string")[0].getAttribute("name");
console.log("getAttribute value :"+txt

 //here i have to send response xml to server

 //I have tried  
 //console.log(xmlDoc.toXMLString()) but won't worked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for a response since XHR requests are asynchronous.

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        parseResponse(xmlhttp.responseXML);
    }
}
```

Source: 
http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I have the response in xmlDoc I have to post this response to server

Comment: Oh I did't even notice the async = false flag. Synchronous xhr is deprecated ( [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request), [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated) ). Don't use those.
I'm not sure what you are talking about. Where are you sending a response to the server? It only looks like you are logging messages to the console. You are missing an XHR call.

Comment: once the changed xml is printed on the console i will then use the ajax post to send the xml data to php server. But i am not getting the changed xml string.

Comment: It's all guesses unless you provide a sample. Preferably jsfiddle.

Comment: Hey chris thanks for your reply have done it through this code.So thought to share code with you.


 aa = xmlDoc.documentElement;
    console.log(aa);
    var string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc);

Then i am going to send this code to server